# Resetting Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devexpress, components, toolbox

I want to bring my toolbox back to its original state, each time i reset my toolbox, devexpress controls come back. I want devexpress controls to be available for me to choose, but I don't want those controls to be added to my toolbox automatically, especially after I click reset toolbox. Any ideas?

what I have tried

- Deleting the tbd files
- deleting the 10.0 folder in
  appdata/roaming/microsoft/visualstudio

Answer (score 1):

If you find any Devexpress entries in the following registry location, just delete it and check by resetting again if it comes still.

64 bit : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ToolboxControlsInstaller

Comment: can you check if the entries are in this location? HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\ToolboxControlsInstaller. if yes, you have to remove them also. Remove the tbd files once again which will cache the entries.

Comment: record or folder doesnt exist

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how they really do to configure the toolbox. you can check with them in their forum.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: Actually, what I did was right click on "any" control (not the toolbox header) and choose "reset toolbox"

Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1565790.aspx/1

Follow these steps

1. Right click on toolbox and press reset button, it will clear all controls added by you.
2. Next click choose item and do not uncheck any checked option.
3. Simply click on your desire .dll control file and press ok, it will add you control and will not disable asp.net controls.